# Draw binary tree given "ATTA" as inorder and postorder traversals

Tags: binary-tree, inorder, postorder

I've been asked to draw a binary search tree that both the in order and post order traversal process the nodes in the order `"ATTA"`. I have tried many different way but it ends up only working for one of the traversal methods.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you're just talking about a regular binary tree, because creating such a binary *search* tree is impossible.

Given that the post-order ends with `A`, we know the root must be `A`.

Given that we only have 2 `A`'s in the in-order, and the root is `A`, we know either the left or right subtrees of the root are empty.

Given that the second last node in the post-order is a `T`, we know the root's child must be a `T`.

From here we can just check the remaining 4 possibilities:

```
               A        A    A        A
              /        /      \        \
             T        T        T        T
            / \      / \      / \      / \
           A   T    T   A    A   T    T   A

Inorder     ATTA     TTAA     ATAT     ATTA
Postorder   ATTA     TATA     ATTA     TATA
```

So the only possibility is:

```
    A
   /
  T
 / \
A   T
```

... and this is not a binary search tree.